# How to replace only text content on an element?

Tags: javascript, text, nodes

I have the following structure:

```
<li>
    <a><i>...</i>Some Text Here!</a>
    <input>
    <a></a>
</li>
```

I want just to change the string `Some Text Here!` under the element `li` without affecting (removing or changing) anything else, that is all its child nodes.

Apparently, `textContent`, if set, removes all descendant elements. Other similar methods seem to do the same thing. I have searched for a while, but no solution seems to solve this.

I can set classes or ids to whatever element you see in the structure, if that helps.

Comment: Wrap that text in a `<span>` tag and use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the element contents and check each `nodeType`  to be a TEXT_NODE

Jquery version:

```
$('a').contents().filter(function () { 
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; 
})
.each(function () { 
    this.nodeValue = 'Something else'; 
});
```

Javascript version:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].childNodes;
for (var i in nodes){
    if (nodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
        nodes[i].nodeValue = 'Something else';
}
```

Comment: same can be done without jquery, its just to show the idea

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: yes, I agree jquery may not be used, but as I said in this case its just a shorter way to show the idea

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already have the `<a>` tag in a variable `anchor`:

```
anchor.lastChild.textContent = 'My text';
```

---

Look at the example below:

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');
anchor.lastChild.textContent = 'Other text';
```

```html
<li>
    <a><i>Lalala...</i>Some Text Here!</a>
    <input>
    <a></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Element.childNodes` which covers text nodes along with elements and replace their `textContent`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].childNodes[1].textContent='Something else';
```

It obviously depends on how many tags there are, whether there are spaces between them, which text you want to replace, etc.

---

A demo:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].childNodes[1].textContent = ' Something else.';
```

```html
<p><i>I’m an element.</i> Some Text Here!</p>
```

Comment: That will also remove the <i></i> tag.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't.</strike> Corrected.

However, for cleanliness sake you should wrap the text in a span and then replace the contents of the span. It's much easier to read, like so:

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a><i>...</i><span class="replace-me">Some text here!</span></a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.replace-me').text('Some new text here now!');
```

Comment: `you can't`  ... yes you can.

Comment: His question doesn't even have `jQuery` tag.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If he didn't tag it, the answer should not use it.

Comment: Well, you'll have to live with it.

Comment: also presumes OP has control over the markup ... often that's not the case

Comment: @AJB http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: Yeah, I really just don't care.

Comment: @AJB ok, no problems. Not sure why you're here then, since this is a place to help the community, and that's not what you're doing. But whatever, take care ;)

Comment: The OP presented a problem and I presented a clean, readable, easy-to-debug way to solve it. If you want to write unnecessarily convoluted code, go nuts. I just hope I never have to read it.

Comment: Also, the vast majority of future readers are going to be using jQuery and have control over their HTML. The pure JS answers are correct, and very informative, but not the ideal way to solve the problem.